# Exit function on backgroundworker.CancellationPending == true

Tags: c#, wpf, backgroundworker

I'm currently trying to get a function of mine to cancel itself when the `backgroundworker.CancellationPending == true`.

I have a class like this:

```
public class ImportPostManager
{
    public event ProgressChangedEventHandler ProgressChanged;

    protected virtual void OnProgressChanged(int progress)
    {
        if (ProgressChanged != null)
        {
            ProgressChanged(this, new ProgressChangedEventArgs(progress, null));
        }
    }

    public void DoSomeStuff()
    {
        while(something == true)
        {
            if(backgroundworker.CancellationPending) return; //Here's my problem

            //KeepDoingStuff and report progress
        }
    }
}
```

I call the function from a form in a `backgroundworker.DoWork()` but HOW can I get the class listen to the `backgroundworker.CancellationPending`? I cannot do it in the `.DoWork()` 'cause it looks like this:

```
void _progressDialog_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
{
    Managers.ImportPostManager.Instance.ProgressChanged += (s, pe) => dialog.ReportProgress(pe.ProgressPercentage, null, pe.ProgressPercentage.ToString() + "%);
    Managers.ImportPostManager.Instance.DoSomeStuff();
}
```

...and I'd prefer not to send the backgroundworker through to the function `.DoSomeStuff()`. Is there a way to use events or something to get what I want? I haven't found anything that can explain how to in a way I can understand...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're sold on `DoSomeStuff` not being passed the worker directly, and assuming it's blocking (which it looks like is fair), your best bet is probably going to be to add a `Func<bool>` parameter to the function.

```
public void DoSomeStuff(Func<bool> ShouldCancel)
{
    while (whatever == whateverElse && !ShouldCancel())
    {
        // Do work
    }
}
```

Then you can call that from your `DoWork` handler.

```
void _progressDialog_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
{
    Managers.ImportPostManager.Instance.ProgressChanged += (s, pe) => dialog.ReportProgress(pe.ProgressPercentage, null, pe.ProgressPercentage.ToString() + "%);
    Managers.ImportPostManager.Instance.DoSomeStuff(() => backgroundworker.CancellationPending);
}
```

That will get evaluated each time, and life will be good.

Although if you're worried about cases like this happening a lot, it might be worth looking into a more advanced form of multithreading, even if just that provided through the `System.Threading.Tasks` namespace. There, you'll have some more options for cancellation. But if you're looking for something quick and simple, adding that function will do the trick, and it will work in multiple contexts, so your helper class won't be tied to use of a Background Worker if you elect against it in the future.

Of course, if you're not bound by use of the `BackgroundWorker.CancellationPending` property (or the, if I recall correctly, `Cancel()` method), you could change that function and check into a `CancellationToken`, and simply call `Cancel()` against that (or rather, against its `CancellationTokenSource`). That's not ideal in some ways, but it would be a bit cleaner down the road if you wound up wanting to move to something a bit more, as I said before, advanced. Of course, you could also very easily layer the token on top of `DoSomeStuff` if you had the function set up now, so it's not like you're bound forever to pick one or the other based on what you choose right this moment.

Comment: This seems to do exactly what I wanted. I will take a look at the other alternatives also, a big thank you Matthew.